# How does bindTo() work in AngularFire?

Tags: binding, angularfire

I am trying to implement three-way binding, and having some problems.

The user can add three different types notes(A, B, C) in the system, and here are how I used the bindTo function, however, when user create a new note, it updates all the new notes when user click one specific type of note. i.e, when user click add note under A type, then click add note under B type, it actually changes all the previous new notes.

```
    $scope.addNote = function(noteType){

    $scope.addANote = false;
    $scope.addBNote = false;
    $scope.addCNote = false;

    var title = "A New Note";
    var content = "Adding Note here";
    var type = "New Type";

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://XXXX/Notes");

    firebaseObj.push({ 
        title: title, 
        content: content,
        type: noteType,  
        username: username,
    });

    switch(noteType) {
        case 'A':
            $scope.addANote = true;
            break;
        case 'B':
            $scope.addBNote = true;
            break;
        case 'C':
            $scope.addCNote = true;
            break;
    } 

    // Get the note Key after user submit a new note
    var noteKey; 
    firebaseObj.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey){
        noteKey = snapshot.key();
    }); 

    var ref = new Firebase("https://XXXX/Notes/" + noteKey);
    var syncNoteObj = $firebaseObject(ref);

    syncNoteObj.$bindTo($scope,"note").then(function(){
        console.log("threeway bingding:" + $scope.notes);
   });    
}
```

And here is the code in the view:

```
                       <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">A <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li>            
                                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-click="addNote('A')">New Note</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>

                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">B <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li>            
                                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-click="addNote('B')">New Note</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>

                          <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">C <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li>            
                                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" ng-click="addNote('C')">New Note</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
```

so I wondering what are the two parameters in bindTo() function, am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i figured this out! :)
I just need to unbind the scope with current note, and here is the solution by using unbind.

```
        syncNoteObj.$bindTo($scope,"note").then(function(unbind){
        console.log("threeway bingding:" + $scope.note);
        $scope.unbindFunction = unbind;
   });

    // Use a flag to track when to unbind the scope with database
    if($scope.unbindingFlag){
        $scope.unbindFunction();
    }
    else{
        $scope.unbindingFlag = true;
    }
```